# POWER BI - SUM dinamically calculated Measure

Tags: powerbi

this is my source SQL table:

| Row | Description | Total | Totaling Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $TGF | Desc 01 | OPB-OPT-FBA-OPFD | 2 |  |
| $MOL | Desc 02 | $TVA-CDL-CDIP | 2 |  |
| $MON | Desc 03 | $MOL-AMFI | 2 |  |
| CDIP | Desc 04 | C0206004 | 0 | 50,0 |
| OPB | Desc 05 | C0800045 | 0 | 45,67 |
| OPB | Desc 06 | C0800015 | 0 | 89 |
| OPB | Desc 07 | C0800014 | 0 | 122,4 |
| FBA | Desc 08 | C0800017 | 0 | -254 |
| CDIP | Desc 09 | C0201002 | 0 | 75 |
| CDIP | Desc 10 | C0200405 | 0 | -77 |

I need to have the Total amount, row by row

- making the SUM of Amount of all rows specified in Total column (splitting by '-')
  if the Totaling Type is 2
- using the original amount
  if Totaling Type is 0.

Is there a way to do this automatically.
If not, what is the best practice to accomplisce the goal.

Thanks a lot.

Riccardo